# IE extra div getting appended which is not part of my code

Tags: html, internet-explorer, polyfills, debouncing

I am facing a weird issue on my website for IE browser. An extra div is getting appended to my DOM and is not part of my code base.

This does not happen on firefox, chrome and safari.

Below is the extra div that is getting appended in my DOM on IE(EDGE)

```
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 1349px; height: 74.99px; font-size: 1em; float: none; position: static; border-spacing: 0;"></div>
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Just found that this div is created using polyfill with the below code

```
        Stickyfill.addOne(document.querySelector('.main-header'));
```

And now on window resize I have an event resize which uses debounce to hold the execution of callback. Please refer the below code

```
const header = document.querySelector('.main-header');
const menuContainer = header.querySelector('.header-nav');

function setTouchMenuHeight() {
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  menuContainer.style.height = bp('<=md') ? `${height}px` : 'auto';
}

setTouchMenuHeight();

window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(setTouchMenuHeight, 150), false);
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your one line into a blank html document and everything looks normal in every browser including Edge.

Is there some javascript or something somewhere as I cannot replicate this.

Comment: I see now that this code above is the *EXTRA* div you say is being created. Put the code that is CAUSING this extra div and maybe we can help.

Comment: I had tough time getting figuring where the code is coming from that to just on IE. Kind of struggling to find the cause

Comment: Without the code that is causing this issue, it is impossible to help.

Comment: @MrCoincidence Have added the code that is causing it. can you check now